# How do I fill the button background with a circle on click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I want to be able to click my button and on the click trigger I want the background to fill up with a circle, much like how a materialistic button would. I know there is a library for this but I'd much rather develop my own because I want to learn.

This is what it would look like when you click, rather than when you move the mouse out of it.

[image]

I've tried playing around with the style of the button, trying to make some animation using storyboards but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                    AutoReverse="True"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

When I click the button I want the background to fill up starting from a circle shape (the button shouldn't be circle shaped), filling up the rest of the button, what I am seeing now is just a fading color of the entire thing which is not what I was expecting.

Comment: Remove/Comment "IsMouseOver" Trigger. It will run animation.

Comment: It doesn't look like click animation. Rather fancy mouse in/out one. To achieve such effect you have to modify button control template and add there `Ellipse` with animation  ( `Width/Height` ? not sure) on show. Button should make this ellipse visible when mouse going out.

Comment: Is this click on / click off functionality? If so, you'd be better to use a ToggleButtton (with an appropriate template) rather than a Button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of such an effect.

I just used a `Rectangle`, not a `Button`, for simplicity. But you surely can apply this technique to any control.

The events `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` are used here, but you can replace them with click events or whatever you need.

```
  <Rectangle Width="150" Height="150" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1">
    <Rectangle.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">
                <!-- we just scale the brush in this animation -->
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(DrawingBrush.Transform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(DrawingBrush.Transform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard Duration="0:0:1">
                <DoubleAnimation From="2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(DrawingBrush.Transform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"/>
                <DoubleAnimation From="2" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(DrawingBrush.Transform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"/>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
      <!-- the rectangle's fill is a brush which can be scaled -->
      <DrawingBrush>
        <DrawingBrush.Transform>
          <!-- the initial scale values are 0, so we don't see the fill -->
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0" ScaleY="0" CenterX="75" CenterY="75"/>
        </DrawingBrush.Transform>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
          <GeometryDrawing Brush="MediumBlue">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="150" RadiusY="150" Center="75,75" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
      </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
```